# How to add summary row per page without group in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

How to add summary row per page without group in SSRS. I don't know how long per page is. and I don't want to fixed on row number because i don't know how long of content per cell.
So Is there anyway to add summary row per page without grouping?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the Summary row to the bottom of the table, and then set the Table Property "Add a page break after" to make sure that's the last row on the page...  This might work better if you use groups though...

Comment: How can i know which row is the last row?